# Instanciar clases para crear objetos mediante arrays en C#

Tags: c#, poo

Estoy con un programa para consola, tengo una clase `Estudiante` con el atributo tipo int `Matricula`.
Tengo 2 constructores, uno con parámetros definidos y otro para que los reciba, al querer crear un array de objetos, cómo hago para que se almacene el valor del atributo `Matricula` en el constructor que recibe parámetros?
Mi código es el siguiente:

Clase Estudiante

```
class Estudiante {
     protected int Matricula;
     }
// Constructor por defecto
public Estudiante() {
     Matricula: 1234567;
     }
//Constructor que recibe parámetros
public Estudiante(int matricula) {
     this.Matricula = matricula;
     }
public virtual string MostrarDatos() {
     return "Matricula: " + this.Matricula;
     }
```

Main

```
Estudiante[] arrayAlumnos = new Estudiante[5];

     //Creando Objetos
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          arrayAlumnos[i] = new Estudiante();
          Console.WriteLine("Matrícula: ");
          int matricula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //En esta línea está mi duda
          }

     //Impresión de datos
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          Console.WriteLine("-------------Estudiante #" + (i + 1) + "-------------\n");
          Console.WriteLine(arrayAlumnos[i].MostrarDatos());
          }
```

Creí y traté de llamar el atributo del constructor de esta forma:

```
Console.WriteLine("Matrícula: ");
int matricula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Pero en VSC `matricula` me aparece como variable local sin uso y al querer imprimir me arroja lo que tengo en el constructor por defecto y no lo que tecleé. ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas "correctas" de hacer esto.. o sea, se puede hacer como mas te guste...

Segun como definiste tu clase (te recomiendo leer sobre clases, ya que por ahi viene tu error), tenes que llenarla...

Esto:

```
int matricula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

No la llena... Si pensas que porque las variables se llamen igual, se va a llenar, entonces de ahi viene tu error... Cada variable tiene un ambito de vida (busca sobre eso tambien)...

Ahora, tenes dos metodos en tu clase para llenar la matricula...

Uno es por el constructor... para eso, entonces, deberia invertir tu codigo, y hacer algo asi:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //pedimo la matricula
    int matricula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    //Creamos una nueva instancia del objeto estudiante, pasandole la matricula
    Estudiante nuevoEstudiante = new Estudiante(matricula);
    //Agregamos al array el nuevo estudiante
    arrayAlumnos[i] = nuevoEstudiante
}
```

El otro metodo, que en tu caso no podes usar, seria pasar la matricula al objeto, si la matricula fuera publica.. pero en tu caso, tu clase no tiene la matricula publica, asi que no podrias, pero igual te dejo el codigo de como seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //pedimos la matricula
    int matricula = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    //Creamos una nueva instancia del objeto estudiante, pasandole la matricula
    Estudiante nuevoEstudiante = new Estudiante();
    nuevoEstudiante.Matricula = matricula;
    //Agregamos al array el nuevo estudiante
    arrayAlumnos[i] = nuevoEstudiante
}
```

Tene en cuenta para que esto funcione, matricula en tu clase debe ser public.